# multi word values gives error in insert query

Tags: php

i am trying to insert a row in table using query->

```
INSERT INTO organizers(username, hotel, city, state, address, type, price1, price2, contact) VALUES ('nitin','moxvox','jodhpur','rajasthan','shastri circle','1','500','0','1000');
```

this query works fine. but when i try to give multi word values like username as 'nitin gehlot' instead of 'nitin': the query fails and returns the error part of response.

i am not much familiar with php: please help me.
php code->

```
$connect= mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
$sqlq=$_GET['query'];
//test
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("data base connection failed: ".
    mysqli_connect_error() .
    " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
}

$query = "$sqlq";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
if(!$result)
{
    die("query is faild" . mysql_error);
}


if(strpos($query,'INSERT')!==false)
                 echo mysqli_insert_id($connect);
 else{
    echo ' {"result" : 1, "message" : [';$i=1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    {
        if($i==1){$i=0;}
        else echo',';
        $j = json_encode($row);
        echo $j;
    }
echo ']}';
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked the column length? in DB?

Comment: I hope you don't use this code in an production environment. Never use a query as an argument of the page uri. It opens your database to the outside world. This might also be the cause of the problem you have.

Comment: i am using column type as text and that does not require length field. is it problem with type text?

Comment: @KIKO, i am using url in an app, will it make any problem: i don't think so.

Comment: @neens: I don't know the environment of 'an app', but if anybody can access your url, in any way, they have complete control over your database.

Comment: I'm right with @KIKOSoftware, if someone put a DELETE * FROM organizers in your url... you may have serious problems. Back to your INSERT query, did you try to paste the query in any PHPmyAdmin with spaces in values ? And, what is the error returned ?

Comment: what was the error? change `mysql_error` to `mysqli_error($connect)` and it should show your error message

Comment: @Kiko, Thanks bro, i was really unaware about that.

Comment: it gives response code 400 error

Comment: Try with username 'a b c' for discard the request length or field length or exist unique constraint.

Comment: `mysql_error()` won't give you anything when you're using MySQLi. It needs to be `mysqli_error($connect)`. Once you fix that, tell us what that function outputs.